# Pands groupby stacked bar show same size for each class

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot stacked bar graph using pandas. But i notice that length of each section in bar graph is same.
Here is the dataframe

```
   sensor      class    mean
0   mq135    0.0    40
1   mq135    1.0    216
2   mq135    2.0    390
3   mq2      0.0    17
4   mq2      1.0    153
5   mq2      2.0    349
6   mq3      0.0    -11
7   mq3      1.0    108
8   mq3      2.0    359
```

This is the code I tried.

```
df.groupby(['sensor', 'class']).size().unstack().plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Here is the ouptut

[image]

Here the length of blue, orange and green segment is same. Though in dataframe, class 0 has smallest values and class 2 has largest value.

So, how can i plot that correctly, where i can show magnitude of each class also.

I should some other function instead of `size`. But i am not sure which one

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to plot the `mean` column value in the bar

```py
(df.groupby(['sensor', 'class'])['mean'].sum()
 .unstack()
 .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True))
```

[image]